# is it legal to pass STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE directly as input HANDLE to WriteFile?

Tags: winapi, writefile

The `WinApi` `WriteFile()` function seems to accept the `STD_xxx_HANDLE` constants directly as a first argument.  I executed the following:

```
#include <windows.h>
main() {
    DWORD bw;

    WriteFile( (void *)STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE,       "output", 6, &bw, NULL);
    WriteFile( GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), "output", 6, &bw, NULL);

    WriteFile( (void *)STD_ERROR_HANDLE,        "error", 5, &bw, NULL);
    WriteFile( GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE),  "error", 6, &bw, NULL);
}
```

The above example writes "output" twice to stdout and "error" twice to stderr.  I have tested on Win XP and Win 7 (I have no access to WINE or Win 10).

I can see `GetStdHandle()` does convert the value (from -11 to 7 in the case of `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE`), but either value works the same as a `WriteFile()` input `HANDLE`.

Is WriteFile implicitly doing `GetStdHandle()` when it recognizes a `STD_xxx_HANDLE` constant as its `HANDLE` input?  I have looked but can't find this documented.

Yes I know if it's not documented, don't do it... I'm simply wondering if I missed something.

Comment: yes, `WriteFile` check `hFile` for `STD_ERROR_HANDLE, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, STD_INPUT_HANDLE` and convert it by using `GetStdHandle`

Comment: My guess is that this was added to support some automatic sourcecode-rewriting tool... and now kept forever in order to maintain backward-compatibility

Comment: Actually, It doesn't make sense to tangle with this. It's considered an invalid handle in other APIs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, this works even on Windows 95 RTM and NT 4 (and XP and 8) so it seems like it is on purpose. I can't tell you why nor how far back in NT 3.x this goes.

But it is undocumented and not really part of the ABI so I would suggest that you continue calling `GetStdHandle` to avoid a nasty surprise in the future.

Comment: Appreciate the additional research.  I have come to my senses and shall continue to religiously perform `GetStdHandle()` mapping, unnecessary though it may be.

Answer (score 0):

[WriteFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile) expects a handle. The `STD_xxx_HANDLE` values are not handles. It is not legal to pass those values to `WriteFile`. You have to convert them to handles by calling [GetStdHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle).

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it's treated as pseudohandles, same as `GetCurrentProcess()` handle.

Try to peek inside `KernelBase.dll`, It checks the `hFile` argument if it's equal to `STD_X_HANDLE` macros.

If yes, the `hFile` handles turn into `NtCurrentPeb()->ProcessParameter->StandardXxx` handle.

And there are other functions that recognized `STD_XXX_HANDLE` macros. GetFiletype , FlushFileBuffers, CloseHandle, and WaitForSingleObject(Ex)also recognize `STD_XXX_HANDLE`.